# What would be the effect of a combination of the Furnunculus Curse and the Jelly-Legs Curse?

Tags: harry-potter

What would happen if the Furnunculus Curse and the Jelly-Legs Curse were used on someone at the same time? Would each curse just simply retain its regular effect, or would there be a new combined effect? If the latter, what would the new effect be?

Comment: -1 for lack of research, although I do understand why you posted this.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - For me the frustration is the OP clearly knew the answer before posting, yet didn't self-answer.

Comment: @Valorum Dunno if Alex is one of them, but some people avoid self-answering because they fear downvotes / it might be seen as a 'rep grab' / they think it's against the rules / ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Posting a Q that you know the answer to (and not self-answering it) seems a lot like posing the site a puzzle to solve rather than a serious question that OP needs to have answered.

Comment: @Valorum I've done it many times, both here and on other sites. (Not counting [puzzling.se]!)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Sure, but when you make it really blatant, you probably shouldn't expect people to pat you on the back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to create little tentacles all over one's face.

> "Thought we'd see what those three were up to," said Fred matter-of-factly, stepping onto Goyle and into the compartment. He had his wand out, and so did George, who was careful to tread on Malfoy as he followed Fred inside.
> "Interesting effect," said George, looking down at Crabbe.
>  "Who used the Furnunculus Curse?"
>  "Me," said Harry
>  "Odd," said George lightly. "I used Jelly-Legs. Looks as though those two shouldn't be mixed. He seems to have sprouted little tentacles all over his face. Well, let's not leave them here, they don't add much to the decor.".
> <sub>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 37 (The Beginning)*</sub>

So it seems like they did mix and it created the effect of spawning little tentacles all over Crabbe's face.